# Referencing disk image on OpenBSD rather than disk partition

Tags: dd, disk, openbsd, disk-image

I am unable to find any online help for the following problem. I am trying to make a disk image copy on OpenBSD from one disk to another.

On Linux, this is how I would do it:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

Unfortunately, the OpenBSD equivalents of the two disks, such as `sd0` and `sd1` have no entries in the `/dev` directory, only their partitions, therefore I am unable to reference them by path as seen above.

So how can I reference the **DISKS** path in OpenBSD commands, instead of their partitions path?

Naturally the disk controller and all connected disks are recognized by the OS and everything is fully operational.

Comment: HI @Tony - are you trying to make a copy of the first disk, or an image of the first disk (the former destroying the second disk, the latter adding as a file to the second disk)??

Answer (score 1):

On OpenBSD, the `c` partition is the entire disk (see [the FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#intro) for details), so in your case, you'll want to read from `sd0c` and write to `sd1c`.  Also, you'll probably want to use the block devices (`rsd0c` and `rsd1c`) instead of the character devices (`sd0c` and `sd1c`).